# Dynamically generate xaml string from a UIElement object

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, uielement

I have a Windows.UI.Xaml.Shape.Path object.How can l generate the xaml string corresponding to that Path object.

Input : Path object

Desired Output : "Path Data="M 120,10 200,L300" Stroke="Black"""

or is there any way to calculate Path Data from Path Bounds property?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
string s_output = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(yourpath);
```

and to reload use

```
System.IO.StringReader stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(s_output);
System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Create(stringReader, new System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings());
Path yourpath= (Path)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.the code is working in Wpf application.But I am developing a Windows8 metro style application,and new framework doesn't have XamlWriter class. So is there any other way to solve the issue?

Comment: @neethu - I have similar problem. Have you been able to solve the XamlWriter issue?

Comment: Maybe xamlwriter is avail. in win8.1?

Comment: another related and actually non-answered (as of 2022-06-28) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442654/uwp-equivalent-to-xamlwriter-for-serializing-xaml