# UWP equivalent to XamlWriter for serializing XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, serialization, win-universal-app

I'm writing an application in which the user is able to place elements onto a canvas and customize them to create a picture. I've been able to save the picture as bitmap but need to be able to serialize and save the canvas's XAML code itself so that I can deserialize and reconstruct the image and let the user edit it again.

XamlWriter is unfortunately not available in UWP but is there any equivalent to serialize XAML? Or would I have to go through the ordeal of inspecting each element in the canvas and saving its position and properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of serializers in UWP: XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, JsonSerializer.
Here is nice article about it:

[Choosing the right serialization engine for your Windows Store app](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2014/01/19/serializing-and-deserializing-data-in-a-windows-store-app.aspx)

and here is one else:

[Saving and Loading App Data (Windows Store C# UWP / 8.1)](http://matthiasshapiro.com/2015/12/10/saving-and-loading-app-data-windows-store-c-uwp-8-1/)

Comment: This does not really answer the OP's question about serializing XAML directly - serializing XAML is not the same thing as serializing POCOs to XML or JSON as it requires interacting with the runtime's XAML service.